# query list view style not applying when angular model updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am building an app with Jquery and angular and have run into a problem.

I have a listview which is using an ng-repeat to create the list items.

when the page loads the list is styled properly. however when i add a new item to the list using a form on the page, it doesn't style the new item properly.

I have tried using the create and refresh methods, I have tried adding a small delay, as has been suggested by answers on similar questions, None of the suggestions i have found are working.

[image: example of the problem]

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%;  border:1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td id="blockA" style="width:25%">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="#ftfcList">
                        <li id="thisCourse.id" ng-repeat="thisCourse in courses.theCourses" ng-click="courses.selected=thisCourse" ng-class="{ftfHighlight:courses.selected.id === thisCourse.id}">{{thisCourse.title}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>

                <td id="blockB" style="width:50%" valign="top">
                    <div ng-show="courses.selected">

                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                            <li><h3>{{courses.selected.title}}</h3></li>
                            <li><b>ID: </b> {{courses.selected.id}}</li>
                            <li><b>length: </b> {{courses.selected.length}}</li>
                            <li><b>Aims: </b></li>
                            <li>{{courses.selected.aims[0]}}</li>
                            <li>{{courses.selected.aims[1]}}</li>
                            <li>{{courses.selected.aims[2]}}</li>
                            <li>{{courses.selected.aims[3]}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-hide="courses.selected">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                            <li>Please select a course (in the left panel) or create a new one to view it's details</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="blockC" style="width:25%">
                    <form style="width:100%">                       
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                            <li><input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="courses.newCourse.title"/></li>
                            <li><input type="text" ng-model="courses.newCourse.id" placeholder="ID (Please use CamelCase)"/></li>
                            <li><b>length: </b> {{courses.selected.length}}</li>
                            <li><b>Aims: </b></li>
                            <li><input type="text" ng-model="courses.newCourse.aims[0]" placeholder="First objective"/></li>
                            <li><input type="text" ng-model="courses.newCourse.aims[1]" placeholder="Second objective"/></li>
                            <li><input type="text" ng-model="courses.newCourse.aims[2]" placeholder="Third objective"/></li>
                            <li><input type="text" ng-model="courses.newCourse.aims[3]" placeholder="Fourth objective"/></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a data-role="button" ng-click="courses.addCourse()">Add this course</a>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and the javascript:

```
var course = [{id: "test2", title: "Test 2", length: "1 day", aims: ["To test that the app can use face to face courses", "To implement back-end support"], notes: "Completley experimental"}, {id: "test", title: "Test", length: "1 day", aims: ["To test that the app can use face to face courses", "To implement back-end support"], notes: "Completley experimental"}];

var app = angular.module("app", []);

var courseController = app.controller("ftfCourseController", function()     {
this.selected;
this.newCourse;
this.theCourses = course;

this.addCourse= function(){
    console.log(this.theCourses);
    this.theCourses.push(this.newCourse);
    this.newCourse = undefined;
    setTimeout(function(){$("#ftfcList").listview("refresh");}, 100);

}

});
```

can anybody see what the problem is here?

thanks for any help you can offer :)

Comment: Can you replicate it in a plunker??

Comment: never heard of plunker before this comment lol, i will try to replicate it now

Comment: i can't seem to get the styles or angular to work on plunker, I also tried jsFiddle and have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  which version of angular you are using.

No need to refresh the view . Angular latest versions no need refresh view after adding or deleting something from scope object. it will render automatically.

please come up with jsfiddle

Comment: I am using 1.4.7.... I can't understand why, but i cannot get the code to work properly on jsFiddle

Comment: are you talking about the CSS classes i've referenced in the HTML? or the actual webpage when the CSS is applied?

Comment: the class which are not applying to you model  @JamieMcAllister